# Combining static and dynamic data in a ComboBox

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, .net-4.0, visual-studio-2013, vsto

```
private void PopulateComboBox()
{
    SqlConnection connection;
    SqlCommand command;
    SqlDataReader reader;
    DataTable dt;

    using (connection = new SqlConnection("connection string here"))
    {
        using (command = new SqlCommand("sql query here", connection))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Load(reader);

                ComboxBox1.ValueMember = "col1";
                ComboxBox1.DisplayMember = "col2";
                ComboxBox1.DataSource = dt;
            }
            connection.Close();

        }
    }
}
```

That above code works fine.  However, I want to add a static entry at index 0 of the ComboBox1 along with the dynamic entries above from the database.  The static index 0 value should be "Select a value".

How do you combine static and dynamic data in a ComboBox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert an empty record into your `DataTable` before binding it to `ComboBox`:

```
dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(reader);

DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
row["col1"] = "Something";
row["col2"] = "Something else";

dt.Rows.InsertAt(row, 0);

ComboxBox1.ValueMember = "col1";
ComboxBox1.DisplayMember = "col2";
ComboxBox1.DataSource = dt;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
comboBox1.Items.Add(new ListItem("Text", "Value"))

comboBox1.Items[0].Text = "Select a value";
```

and in your sql code:

```
.......

using (reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Load(reader);
               comboBox1.Items.Add("col1");
               ...
             }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `dt.Rows.InsertAt(Datarow row, int pos)`  to insert a new row at position 0 before binding the combobox.